# How do i create/overwrite a mongoDB v2.4 collection based on aggregate result?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

```
db.userData.aggregate({
$group : {  "_id"  : "$user.id",
                "count": { "$sum":1 },
                "ids": { "$push": "$_id" },
                "content": { "$push": "$text" }
              }
},  {$match:{"count": {"$gt": 1}}
})
```

The result from the above routine should create or replace a mongoDB v2.4 collection, how do i go by this in an efficient way. Thank you.

*Edit #1*

```
db.selUserTweets.aggregate({
  $group : {  "_id"  : "$user.id",
                "count": { "$sum":1 },
                "ids": { "$push": "$_id" },
                "content": { "$push": "$text" }
              }
},  {$match:{"count": {"$gt": 1}}
},  {$out :{"count": -1}
})
```

*On execution*

```
Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0
()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37
([object Object],[object Object],[object Object])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866
@(shell):8

uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$out'",
    "code" : 16436,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Comment: add an out option as a last step in your pipeline array i:e: 
{ $out: "a_collection_name" }

Comment: I think '$out' is not supported until v2.6

Comment: You are right but that's your only option I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Update MongoDB to at least 2.6 so you can use the [$out](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator which does exactly what you want to do.

When you do not want to update to a more recent version for some reason, another option is to rewrite your aggregation as a [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) with the [out-option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-out-cmd).